# Установка php-fpm 5.6 на debian wheezy

Tags: php, linux, debian, apt-get

И так и сяк, одинаково упирается в `PHP Version 5.4.45-1~dotdeb+7.1`.

Прописал

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56-zts all
```

Потом

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5-fpm
apt-get upgrade
```

Может где-то в конфигах или где симлинк указывается?

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу, полный вывод команды, которая завершается ошибкой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился очень просто

Не хорошо так делать, конечно. Лучше обновить систему. Однако, вместо `wheezy` можно указать более новую версию debian.

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
```

Успех.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Обычно, при обновлении делаю замену всех, связанных с php, т.е.:

```
apt-get install php5-fpm php5-cli php5
```

Comment: `Уже установлена самая новая версия php5.` Итог: php 5.4